# S3 life cycle policy - move to SIA only if size bigger than 128KB

Tags: amazon-s3

**Usecase description:**
I'm planning to set a life cycle policiy to move objects from frequent access to infrequent access automatically after 30 days. but in the bucket, there are some small files that are less than 128KB and I don't want to switch their tiring because of the following limitation in Standard - IA:

> "Standard - IA is designed for larger objects and has a minimum object size of 128KB. Objects smaller than 128KB in size will incur storage charges as if the object were 128KB. For example, a 6KB object in S3 Standard - IA will incur S3 Standard - IA storage charges for 6KB and an additional minimum object size fee equivalent to 122KB at the S3 Standard - IA storage price. Please see the Amazon S3 pricing page for information about Standard - IA pricing."

most of the data in the bucket are logs files and are automatically generated by different services and published to s3 for storing them(can't do a lot of work on app side that put the files in the bucket).

**Question:**
Is it possible to set a life cycle policy that applies to all objects in the bucket to move the bucket objects after 30 days to standard infrequent access tier if the object size is less than 128KB? and if not possible any recommendations or way around this limitation to not transfer these files?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, by default AWS S3 lifecycle policies do not move objects smaller than 128 kilobytes to S3 IA

> **Objects smaller than 128 KB** – For the following transitions, Amazon S3 does not transition objects that are smaller than 128 KB:
>
> From the S3 Standard or S3 Standard-IA storage classes to S3 Intelligent-Tiering or S3 Glacier Instant Retrieval.
>
> From the S3 Standard storage class to S3 Standard-IA or S3 One Zone-IA.

source:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-transition-general-considerations.html